# Intellij IDEA not recognizing Android library resources

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play-services

I have added the Google Play Services as a library project to my Android project in Intelli-J but it appears that the resources are still not being recognized by the IDE. I am getting the following error when the app attempts to inflate the map:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code for the fragment in the layout XML.

```
    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraZoom="13"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="false"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
```

In `maps_attrs.xml` in the Google Play Project, `<declare-styleable name="MapAttrs">` "MapAttrs" is highlighted in red.

The code functions correctly when compiled in Eclipse.

Does anyone know how to get IDEA to recognize the resources?

Comment: Check that library project is configured correctly and is added to the dependencies for the main project. JAR file if the library project should have **Export** option enabled. [Check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96525) for the tips how to import library projects without sources in IDEA. If it doesn't help, share a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: An example project is here: https://github.com/TheDirtyCalvinist/MapStyleable

As far as I can tell, everything is correct in the project properties. I'm not having an issue finding the classes, just the resource properties, in this particular case the styleable attributes.

Comment: It appears that Intellij is mis-generating the google-play-services R.java file. When the google-play-services library is built in Eclipse, the R.java gets filled out, but not in Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround by reinstalling the Google Play Services from Android, compiling it in Eclipse, and then reattaching it to my IDEA project and redirecting the R.java output of the google-play-services-lib to a dummy directory (Changing the directory for R.java output under the compiler tab of the google-play-services module's Android face from '.../gen' to '.../_gen'). I'm still not absolutely sure what was causing it.

It looks like JetBrains is going to change this behavior in 12.1: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99045

Comment: Current behaviour of the IDE should not cause any problem unless you use any external tools generating additional files in "gen" folder or processing its content, so it looks like a bug. I've tried to build the project from github but I've got 2 other runtime errors: "Google Maps Android API only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 andabove" and "API key not found". It seems I managed to fix them, but after it the application ran correctly without runtime errors. Could you create an issue in JetBrains tracker and attach sample project to it?